# Boost asio correctly reading from a socket

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I'm familiar with regular sockets and to read unformatted data from them I usually use `recv()` function, and this is what I expect from it,

> For connection-oriented sockets (type SOCK_STREAM for example), calling recv will return as much data as is currently available—up to the size of the buffer specified.

But I'm getting confused with Boost Asio, for example `async_read_some`,

> The read operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes. Consider using the async_read function if you need to ensure that the requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation completes.

What does that mean? What should I expect when calling `async_read_some`, how much data will it read? Can I read everything that is being available on the socket in for example 32 bytes chunks and be sure that I will not miss any data that is being available on the socket?

Lets say I will be reading 32 bytes at a time and now I'm having 36 bytes incoming data, how that will be handled with `async_read_some`? (one 32 bytes and then the rest?!)

Im new to Boost asio and concept of asynchronous programming, so please forgive any mistake I might have in explaining my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I worked with boost::asio and would expect the following:

`async_read_some` function will try to read as much data as can. It's limited by buffer size. The indicator for data absence should be `boost::asio::error::eof` error which is supposed to be correctly handled in a "handler" you pass along with buffer.

`async_read` will not call the "handler" until the whole required amount of bytes is read.

Comment: What does "indicator of absence" means? Like when I have 36 bytes, it would read one 32 bytes and read 4 bytes and then return `boost::asio::error::eof`? Also how would I check for `boost::asio::error::eof`, against error_code?

Comment: > Like when I have 36 bytes, it would read one 32 bytes and read 4 bytes and then return boost::asio::error::eof?
yes

> Also how would I check for boost::asio::error::eof, against error_code?
1) Read the docs - https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html.
2) You call async_read_some() with buffer and handler. handler will be called after the read operation completes. Handler has error code as function parameter, so you can check eof  in handler, it's a correct place for this. Also check docs ^^^

Comment: 3) The same concept with handler for async_write operation.
Example of TCP async server, you can find here usage of async_write + handler with error code parameter.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html

Comment: NOTE on "it would read one 32 bytes and read 4 bytes and then return":
One read operation will read one block of data. So, if you call async_read once, then you will get one handler call with data in the buffer. You need to call read operation once again to get more bytes. At the end of this cycle no bytes will be in stream, and the eof error is the indicator of it.

In general, read should be in loop even if they are async. You can create handler with extra parameters, bind `this` to one of them, so handler will have an access to class in which read loop exists.

Comment: Don't forget that if object of your class is cleaned, call by it's `this` will cause to UB.